# Android studio not started

Tags: windows, android-studio

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Fatal error initializing 'com.vladsch.md.nav.MdPlugin' [Plugin: com.vladsch.idea.multimarkdown]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:571)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:59)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:154)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.createInstance$lambda$1(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Cancellation.computeInNonCancelableSection(Cancellation.java:99)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.createInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:132)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:92)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:77)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl$createInitOldComponentsTask$1.invoke(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:394)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl$createInitOldComponentsTask$1.invoke(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:392)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplicationImpl$appInitializedListeners$1$1$2$1.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt:139)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:788)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:758)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.intellij.openapi.editor.colors.EditorColorsManager.addEditorColorsListener(com.intellij.openapi.editor.colors.EditorColorsListener, com.intellij.openapi.Disposable)'
    at com.vladsch.md.nav.MdPlugin.initComponent(MdPlugin.kt:130)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:45)
    ... 25 more

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
E:\AS\jbr
```

I've tried uninstalling/installing delete directories in users/name/...Android studio
nothing helps
Can anyone advise what to do
Otherwise it happened after I wanted to import the project from github
https://github.com/adaptech-cz/Tesseract4Android
After downloading/cloning via start Android Studio something was installed /I didn't notice what/ AS rebooted and didn't boot anymore.

Comment: I'd guess the plugin `com.vladsch.idea.multimarkdown` is not compatible with your version of android studio and needs deleting

Comment: Right, I deleted it, it was on its way 
c:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\plugins\

and Android Studio was up and running!
Thank you very much for the quick and good advice !

Comment: I can't find the plugin from macos AndroidStudio/plugins folder. What is its filename/folder name?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, and solve with restarting winnat.

1. Run CMD with administrator

- net stop winnat
- net start winnat

2. Run Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

The error log identifies the plugin `com.vladsch.idea.multimarkdown` as the problem, if you don't need that plugin simply remove it. Otherwise you'll need to find a version compatible with your current version of android studio